# Prevent Chrome and Vivaldi from interpreting mouse movement as touch events

Tags: mouse, google-chrome, touchscreen

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell Inspiron 7547, which has a touchscreen. Whenever I use Chrome/Chromium or Vivaldi, any mouse (i.e. touchpad) movement within the window is interpreted as a "touchmove" event. (This is based on trying it with the event tester at http://rbyers.github.io/eventTest.html.) This means everything is constantly scrolling and tabs are detaching and it's totally unusable.

Disabling the "enable touch events" flag in Chrome/Chromium doesn't seem to make any difference, which suggests that maybe it's not just a browser issue, although strangely the mouse works normally in Firefox.

Relatedly, I've disabled tap-clicking in system settings, but tap clicking still works in the affected browsers.

Is there any way to get these browsers to work properly with my mouse?